# What is the efficient way to store UUID generated in Java to Oracle DB? Will removing or not removing hyphen in the UUID be any use?

Tags: oracle, store, uuid

What is the efficient way to store UUID generated in Java to Oracle DB? Will removing or not removing hyphen in the UUID be any use - storage/performance?

Will storing 
`07b319dc-7e64-4047-a3e3-63ab43864d81` as it is
OR storing
`07b319dc-7e64-4047-a3e3-63ab43864d81` as `07b319dc7e644047a3e363ab43864d81`
 make any difference?

Comment: I would think that storing it as `RAW(16)` is the most efficient in terms of storage, if that is what "efficient" means to you.

Comment: Bug converting from/to string adds an extra step that affects performance... It'd help to know what exactly user is worried about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removing the hyphens will save you exactly 4 characters per row on the database, which is not really worth the effort. Oracle will not be significantly slower or faster because of these four characters. Even worse, if you want to select the the value back to your Java application and recreate an `java.util.UUID` object, you need to re-insert the hyphens at the correct place.

If you want to save a little memory on the database, `RAW(16)` (as vcsjones mentioned in the comment of your question) would have the smallest footprint. However, if you want to use the `RAW` type, you need to disassemble the UUID into a `byte[]` array. This is a bit tricky since `java.util.UUID` only returns a `String` representation or two `long` values. Recreation of a `UUID` object from a `byte[]` array is even trickier.

Comment: Agreed, now if I am storing it as a string; the question is whether it will have any impact on the indexes created on this field?

Comment: The index might require some more storage space but in terms of performance there should not be a significant difference. Additionally, a query for a UUID does only make sense with a `=` in the `WHERE` clause which is very efficient on indexed columns.

Comment: Note that I've encountered a case where Oracle was using full table scans on update of a table with ~250K rows whose PK was a UUID stored as String, because the PK index couldn't be stored in memory => probably that in this case, using RAW(16) will show better performance.