# Does Oracle 19 database support UUID columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, uuid

Does Oracle 19 database support UUID columns, to store for example `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`?

I know that Oracle NoSQL supports this, but I'm looking for Oracle SQL.

If not how should I implement it? A 36 character varchar2 column with constraint to check for the value?

Comment: [Possibly related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13610381/266304)

Comment: use string as oracle defines it as subtype of string https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/using-uuid-data-type.html

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You do realize that the example you gave is NOT a UUID, right? What are letters like `z` and `r` doing in a UUID? Rather, if you are asking about a UUID data type (as distinct from just "string"), you would want some constraints that would NOT allow a string like that to be stored in a UUID column.

Comment: The recommendation is to use `raw` for that

Comment: @nbk: you are linking to the manual of the "Oracle NoSQL" - that's something different than the Oracle database (which is a relational database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments mention, while `UUID` isn't a supported type, you can easily implement a `UUID` column like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example
(
  uuid CHAR(36) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(uuid, '^[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$'))
);
```

Here is a DBFiddle showing the check constraint in action ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d473346f1b104d1513baa9a11b847725))

Comment: Perhaps a bit more elegant would be to use the `[:xdigit:]` character class instead of `[0-9a-f]`.

Comment: @mathguy The start of string and end of string anchors aren't really necessary as the pattern takes up all 36 characters of the fixed length 36 character column.  However, I do like the idea of using the character class instead of defining valid characters.

Comment: Good point, I missed the data type you used. For the regex engine, though, it is still much more efficient to include the anchors, even if logically they are not required. The regex engine is not smart enough to make that logical deduction, and if a match starting at the first position is not found, it will still try to find a match starting at the second position, at the third,  ... Adding the anchors (at least the starting one) helps the regexp engine avoid these wasteful checks.

Comment: @mathguy Good point. That makes sense.