# Oracle DB data type for id

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

generally in postgrest the uuid data type is used for the id,

```
create table "users"
(
    "id"         uuid                           not null,
    "password"   varchar(255)                   not null,
    "name"       varchar(255)                   not null,
    "surname"    varchar(255)                   not null,
    "created_at" timestamp  null,
    "updated_at" timestamp  null,
    "deleted_at" timestamp  null
);
alter table "users"
    add primary key ("id");
```

but in oracle it gives me an error :

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype
> Blockquote
> ORA-00904: "id": invalid identifier

So, what type of data is recommended to use?
Because BIGINT is not allowed either. Is only NUMBER used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572989/does-oracle-19-database-support-uuid-columns

Comment: Do you particularly want (or need) a UUID - which could be RAW and defaults with `sys_guid()`? With a numeric key you can have [an identity column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH), which is backed by a (numeric) sequence.

Comment: It's number data type a good choice?

Comment: Using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice as you then have to use quoted identifiers and the exact same case wherever those identifiers are used. You should be using unquoted identifiers. (And, in Oracle, `VARCHAR` is an alias for `VARCHAR2`)

Comment: **NEVER** store a password as plain-text. If you need to store a password then you should store a hash (or better, a salted hash) of the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what type of data is recommended to use?

Whatever is most appropriate for your **business** case.

---

- If you have data that is uniquely identified by a short human-readable string then you can use `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` as a primary key.
- If you have data that is uniquely identified by a numeric column then use a `NUMBER`.
- If you have one value-per-second (or day) then you could use a `DATE`.

If you are generating a surrogate primary key then:

- If you want to use an `IDENTITY` column then you will need a `NUMBER`.
- If you want to generate a GUID then you can use a `RAW` and default to `SYS_GUID()` or could use a `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` for a formatted GUID.

The point is that there is no recommended data type for a primary key; it is whatever is most appropriate for the particular business case that you are implementing.